# c++: what is "suitable alignment" to point to an object of a particular size?

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

the docs for [operator new](http://This%20function%20is%20required%20to%20return%20a%20pointer%20suitably%20aligned%20to%20point%20to%20an%20object%20of%20the%20requested%20size.) say

> This function is required to return a pointer suitably aligned to point to an object of the requested size.

What's the definition of suitable alignment? and is `std::malloc` returning suitable alignment for a specific size?

Answer (score 1):

“Suitable alignment” is up to the implementation. It depends on the alignment requirements of the target hardware and on how the compiler lays out data objects. So both `operator new` and `malloc` are intimately connected to the compiler that they work with.

Comment: but does that mean, when replacing operator new globally, that if one implements it using malloc, one can expect that this requirement is met?

Comment: @user1282931 Yes, as long as you don't mix between using new (with delete) and malloc (with free) as they use different internal data structures.

Comment: @MaximV — as long as you make sure that you only `free` pointers that you got from `malloc` and only `delete` pointers that you got from `operator new` you can use both schemes.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes exactly right, I personally prefer to use `new` and `delete` as you can overload them to trace memory allocation, but both are perfectly valid for allocating memory on the heap.